# Taylor product rule

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm going through a review class on calculus and right now we are covering Taylor series. We were given a product rule, but the derivation of this rules didn't make sense to me. I can't figure out how the author came to the conclusions. Here is the rule

### Product rule for Taylor polynomials

Suppose we consider the product of a function with a factor $(x-a)$, in other words $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$. Then the $(n+1)$th order Taylor polynomial $T_{n+1}(x)$ of $f(x)$ centered at the point $x=a$  is given in terms of the $n$th order Taylor polynomial $T^g_n(x)$ of $g(x)$ as follows
$$
T_{n+1}(x)=(x-a)T^g_n(x)
$$

By applying this rule iteratively we also find that the $(n+k)$th order Taylor polynomial $T_{n+k}(x)$ of the function $f(x)=(x-a)^kg(x)$ centered at $x=a$ is given in terms of the $n$th order Taylor polynomial $T^g(x)$ of $g(x)$ as
$$
T_{n+k}(x)=(x-a)^k T^g_n(x)
$$

In fact, product rules exist for other kinds of products of function. However, the one presented above will suffice in a great many cases.

I've been at it trying to derive the rule for quite some time now, and I can't figure it out. (I think I'm just too tired) I would really appreciate a more detailed derivation of this rule.

Comment: Which one of these rules are you trying to derive? for $k=1?$ for general $k?$ for other kinds of products?

Comment: @AnneBauval For both, $k=1$ as well as general $k$. The description that I have given is the exact description that we were given in class.

Comment: If it is for both, let us focus on the first one. Where precisely are you lost? You only need to recall the definition of the $n$-th Taylor polynomial for a function $f$ at a point $a.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I have tried, but I just can’t see it. Honestly, it feels like one of those cases which is so simple, that once you see it you say to yourself, how did I miss it. But I just don’t see it. I would appreciate help with it.

Comment: What is the definition of the $n$-th Taylor polynomial for a function $f$
 at a point $a?$

Comment: @AnneBauval $T_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^{k}$

Comment: ([My definition](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9veloppement_limit%C3%A9#D%C3%A9finitions) was more general, being merely a polynomial approximation of $f$ not requiring the  $f^{(k)}(a)$'s to be defined, but never mind, let us take [yours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).) Well then, roll up your sleeves: notice that (if $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ then) for $k>0,$ $f^{(k)}(a)=g^{(k-1)}(a),$ and derive that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k=(x-a)\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac1{j!}g^{(j)}(a)(x-a)^j.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval It seems like I have some kind of a math block and I feel pretty dumb for asking the next question. How did you go from $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ to $f^{(k)}(a)=g^{(k-1)}(a)$?

Comment: Calculate $f^{(k)}(x)$ by induction. Alternatively, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule